# How do I cheaply carry a separate extra check-in bag in domestic flights in India?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, india, domestic-travel, connecting-flights

I have booked a (return) ticket from Boston to New Delhi. In this flight, I'll be carrying two 23 kg bags. However, My destination is Kolkata. So, I'll be buying another (return) ticket from New Delhi to Kolkata, which is a domestic flight.

But **most of the domestic flights in India does not allow two check-in bags**. How do I manage to transfer the extra 23 kg bag?

I have checked with Jet Airways. They are saying that after the allowance of free check-in bag (23 kg with their US-payment site), I have to pay INR 300-500/kg. This will cost me huge for another 23 kg.

For Air India, they also do the same on the weight-basis, not on the piece-basis.

Any suggestions from the experienced people?

Comment: Take less baggage.  Baggage rules are baggage rules, you can't scam 46 kg when the limit is 23 k, maybe you can get away with 26 or 27, but not double.  Next time consider booking your ticket all the way to Kolkata, then your international rules override the domestic rules.

Comment: AFAIK a single BOS-DEL-CCU booking should allow you to carry baggage as per longest (BOS-DEL) leg, but as you have already purchased ticket for one leg that option is not available to you. You can perhaps book a Business class ticket for DEL-CCU as business class usually has a better baggage allowance.

Comment: Or you can sponsor one of your relatives to come and meet you in DEL and both of you fly out with one piece each (Air India allows 25 kg per pax on domestic) ;)

Comment: Okay, I thought there would be some other airlines which could help on this or have less baggage fees if I am travelling from an international flight, even on a separate ticket.

Comment: Flights on separate tickets are completely ignored when you are dealing with another flight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched through the web and contacted customer care numbers of different airlines. Here's the deal that I found the best.

The deal is only available if you book through Indigo's own website. Indigo offers 15 kg check-in baggage, by default for their domestic flights. Additionally, if you choose Student option (they accept foreign universities as per their customer care), they give discounted ticket and a 10 kg of extra baggage. So now, you have `(15+10) = 25` kg of checked in baggage free.

If you have an international connection within 24 hrs before / after the domestic leg, you can book more check-in baggage in very cheap cost. For example, 30 kg of more check-in baggage costs only Rs. 1500/- All this should be done online with Indigo's website.