# Extra luggage in India

Tags: luggage, india, jet-airways, skyteam

There is a similar question here:
[How do I cheaply carry a separate extra check-in bag in domestic flights in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101228/how-do-i-cheaply-carry-a-separate-extra-check-in-bag-in-domestic-flights-in-indi)

I am traveling on a domestic flight in India, and need to take two luggages with me (max 23 kgs each). All domestic airlines I checked only allow 15kgs, with extra luggage charges of 500 rupees/kg. so for 31 kgs extra I will play an amount 9300 INR which is three times the flight ticket.

I can pay for a business class ticket, but don't know the rules for baggage for it. I also have SkyTeam Elite with Delta which Jet Air has *perhaps* a partnership with, but I do not know the baggage rules either (and neither did Jet Air's call center!)

How can I do that?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: if would be helpful if you mention which cities you are travelling in India. Will it be continuous journey or breaking.

Comment: I think the baggage allowance in business class on Jet Airways is 30 kg.

Comment: @siddhantKumar IXC to DEL. I can take a train or taxi I know, but my question is specifically for flights. The cost of the flight does not matter (business, economy whatever) .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I cheaply transport lots of baggage when travelling domestically in India when coming in or going out on an international flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132206/how-can-i-cheaply-transport-lots-of-baggage-when-travelling-domestically-in-indi)

Answer (score 1):

for Chandigarh to Delhi, use Air India. They provide 25kg checkin free.

If you go early for check in they can allow 2 bags within 25kg (although tkt says one bag).

Forgot to add, it's economy. You don't have to book business class.